# Movies reviews category error - NTLK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm learning sentiment analysis by testing out NLTK's built-in movie reviews corpus. I'm trying to extract the file ids from the positive category:

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr

poslearn1 = mr.fileids(categories="pos"[667:])
```

but I keep getting the error:

"Category not found"

even though `poslearn1 = mr.fileids(categories="pos"[:667])` seems to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for some time now.

Comment: The code that seems to work is identical to the one generating the error? Or is your issue that it runs fine, but doesnt find the category that you know exists?

Comment: have edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line doesn't make any sense

```
poslearn1 = mr.fileids(categories="pos"[:667])
```

Its simply equivalent to writing

```
poslearn1 = mr.fileids(categories="pos")
```

You can try following

```
categories="pos"[:667]
print(categories) # prints pos
```

And this line

```
categories="pos"[667:]
```

will find nothing other than empty string. It is trying to produce a substring of "pos" starting at index `667` which doesn't exist.